# Why does curvature reduce the inward attractive force of molecules?

Tags: water, curvature, surface-tension

This question concerns the first 2 paragraphs of this [text](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/meteo300/node/676).

I am struggling to visualize why molecules on the flat surface experience more net inward force than those on a curved surface. If we have 2 surfaces of water which both have the same number of molecules and one is curved, why does the curved one experience less inward force, if anything, to my mind it seems as it would experience more force as it is more compact. Additionally, does bigger curvature imply less surface tension and why?

Comment: Surface tension has two units $N/m$ and $J/m^2$, that is, it is inversely proportional to the surface area. A droplet of water becomes a droplet to increase the area, that is, to decrease the energy "cost". This could be the answer to your question.

Comment: For the connection between the microscopic and macroscopic description of surface tension check out [Why is surface tension a force parallel to the interface?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.3854)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take a liquid one that is laid flat and one that has a curvature, you will see that the one with the curvature lacks some of the neighbors that are there in a flat surfaced one, thus less hydrogen bonding, thus less inward force.

Comment: This is what I don't understand, why would it lack neighbors? It is still the same number of molecules and the fact that they are curved does not mean those molecules are gone. Isn't it still the same number of neighbors only in one case they lie on a straight line and in the other on a curve?

Comment: There will not be the same number of neighbors because in both cases the density of the liquid is the same in both flat and curved ones.

Comment: You say that I will "see" that the one with curvature lacks some of the neighbors. How do I see that? The point of my question is how to visualize this.

Comment: Okay, I will help you visualize, so you know if a liquid has a certain density that means only a certain amount of particles can be in proximity with another particle, so let's take for example the liquid, in this case, has 10 particles surrounding in a circle around it(we are talking about the particles which are not on the surface). So now if you look at the particles surrounding ones at the surface, the flat part can only form a semicircle around the particles, as there are no particles above it.

Comment: But in the case of the curvature one, it will not even be able to form a semicircle. Thus, we know that a curved one has fewer neighbors than the flat one.

Answer (score 0):

> why molecules on the flat surface experience more net inward force than those on a curved surface. If we have 2 surfaces of water which both have the same number of molecules and one is curved, why does the curved one experience less inward force, if anything, to my mind it seems as it would experience more force as it is more compact.

Due to cohesive forces, liquid gets pulled uniformly in all directions. But in case of the surface molecules, there are no molecules to pull the surface molecules outwards. Hence the molecules have a net inward force.

This inward force is unbalanced and it causes the surface to change its shape to a more curved one and the density of the molecules at the surface would be higher than the density of the liquid because the molecules are closer due to the unbalanced force.

When the water surface gets curved, The net inward force is completely nullified by tangential cohesive forces, pressure gradient forces $\Delta P = \frac{2\sigma}{r}$ (force due to higher pressure inside the water drop). etc. At this point, the net inward force would be $0$.

This makes the flat surface have a higher net inward force than a curved surface since the forces are balanced in the curved surface.

> does bigger curvature imply less surface tension and why?

According to Laplace Equation,

$\Delta P = \frac{2\sigma}{r} \implies \Delta P\propto \frac{1}{r}$

And since the pressure gradient decreases as the radius of curvature increases, we can say that the surface tension force decreases as radius of curvature increases as the pressure gradient forces are the major forces which nullify the inward pull of the surface molecules.

It is important to note that the pressure force acts perpendicular to the surface of the liquid.

The shape of the liquid is decided by the equilibrium of the forces of surface tension, pressure gradient and gravity.